# Why my sprite has a colored background? / Why transparent sprite has a background?

Tags: opengl, png, textures, sprite, sfml

I'm writing simple piece of code that show a sprite with transparent background on a green background. Now I have a problem with my sprite, It has a colored background (I can change the color so it's not bug) while it should appear without any background on my main background!

it seems to me, the problem is that when the texture get mapped to the colored quad all the alpha values are set the same as quad color value because:

1. the PNG image is fine and has a transparent background
2. I port the image with alpha channel cuz i can determine the color behind texture so its not import problem
3. my blending should be okey cuz the whole quad blend okey

here my texture and blending code:

```
//Texture Configuration
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glGenTextures(10, texNo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texNo[0]);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );  
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );      
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    sfTexture[0].loadFromFile("image.png");
    sf::Texture::bind(&sfTexture[0]);


    //Blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and my drawing code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex2d(0,0);
        glVertex2d(220,0);
        glVertex2d(220,300);
        glVertex2d(0,300);


        glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texNo[0]);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2d(xpos+0,ypos+0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2d(xpos+30,ypos+0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2d(xpos+30,ypos+30);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2d(xpos+0,ypos+30);
        //glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glEnd();
```

Update: I tried GL_MODULATE instead of GL_DECAL

Image with GL_MODULATE without blending:
[GL_MODULATE without blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABLqZ.jpg)

Image with GL_MODULATE with blending:
[GL_MODULATE with blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRvVo.jpg)

Comment: Can't you just drop the glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL ); line? Why do you need it? I'm not familiar with it but apparently it blends your texture color (bunny) with the quad color (red), which is exactly what you do not want.

Comment: Without Decal the BG still is not transparent, 
GL_DECAL determine that textured polygons are drawn using the colors from the texture map (rather than taking into account what color the polygons would have been drawn without the texture).

Comment: @Darky I think it would be easier to set the Color to (1,1,1,1) and use the default `GL_MODULATE`. The problem is that that if you use `GL_DECAL` then the output fragment uses the alpha to blend with the `glColor` of the polygon and write the alpha given in `glColor4f`. But if that doesn't fix it, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: [this link](http://waltermilner.com/joglblogl/texblend.htm) seems relevant and confirms what @FullFrontalNudity said.

Comment: I tried GL_MODULATE before, GL_MODULATE itself work fine but with Blending being enable my background vanish for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Darky which background? The green one or the one in the image? Before you draw the green thing make sure to set `glColor4f(0,1,0,1);` and `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);` to disable the texture.

Comment: I updated pictures under my main post, with modulate without blending the sprite have a strange BG and when I turn on blending the Sprite is fine but there is no BG (main) anymore.
btw I even turned off gl_texture_2d before drawing main BG so it's strange that BG fade even thought there is no depth test and its alpha is 1, and clearcolor alpha is 0..

Comment: @Darky oh, I completely forgot. Haven't used fixed pipeline for a long time. You are only allowed to use certain commands between `glBegin()` and `glEnd`, so use only `glTexCoord` `glColor` `glVertex` and other similar commands. So use one `glBegin()/glEnd()` combo for the background, then change the settings and then use another `glBegin()/glEnd()` to draw the sprite.

 The `glBindTexture` and `glEnable/glDisable` should throw `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when you put the there, you can check it with `glGetError()`.

Comment: Oww, It's working now! Special thx!
My problem is solved but i have a little question too, as I was w8ing for response I remembered the problem with Begin and End blocks as you said and i defined 2 block but instead of just enabling and disabling Texture and Blend i decided to Put initTexture after drawing BG, everything was ok but the Texture wouldn't load (just texture). It appear that i can load texture only in Main() and no other place, why?

Comment: @Darky I don't really know, if you called `glGenTextures` every frame without deleting them then you'd run into your max texture limit pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PeterT said in comments:
It would be easier to set the Color to (1,1,1,1) and use the default GL_MODULATE. The problem is that that if you use GL_DECAL then the output fragment uses the alpha to blend with the glColor of the polygon and write the alpha given in glColor4f.
Also You are only allowed to use certain commands between glBegin() and glEnd, so use only glTexCoord glColor glVertex and other similar commands. So use one glBegin()/glEnd() combo for the background, then change the settings and then use another glBegin()/glEnd() to draw the sprite.